# Return php query to json null why?

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

Could someone please help me, how should I do ?, please help.

```
$resultG = mysqli_query($db,"select * from Rubrica where ID_Dispositivo = '$UserID' ");
                                    $response = array();
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultG)){
                                        $response[] = $row;
                                    }
echo json_encode($response);
```

The response is D/doInBackground(Resp): []

why is null????

Comment: Are you try to print_r($row);

Comment: Try the query on the database directly. Nobody except you can know if there is data matching your query...

Comment: why row?, i need to ecode to json

Comment: it gives data but don't return

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_assoc returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row. Try to change

```
$resultG = mysqli_query($db,"select * from Rubrica where ID_Dispositivo = '$UserID' ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultG)){
echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!